# Нужна помощь с настройкой Yoast SEO

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

Пытаюсь настроить seo оптимизацию на сайте используя Yoast SEO (только учусь).
Через плагин настроил страницу следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в гугле сниппет выглядит следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Почему отличается meta-description?
2. Почему отличается язык?

в google search console делал запрос на индексацию

Answer (score 0):

1. С недавних пор Google изменяет title и description если (по мнению Google) он не соответствует содержанию страницы. По некоторым исследованиям изменения происходят в 70% случаев(description)Ваши настройки плагина здесь не при чем. Как вариант, попробуйте создать description с менее спамным вхождением ключевых слов.
2. Может быть по той же причине, а может быть вы вставили текст в перемешку на разных языках. Как минимум поправьте на сайте lang="uk" на тот язык, который вы хотите использовать на данной странице.